# delete row from the list

Tags: android

when i am deleting a row from the database then it deletes row successfully ,, suppose that i had deleted the row 2 from the database then when i click on row 3 then it shows the content of row 4 . on clicking row 1 its working fine but on clicking row 2 it pop up with force closed and error is CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0 ... 
  on clicking the row it shows text value saved in that row ...
  i have populated listview by simplecursoradapter .
please someone do some help

Comment: Have u called notifydatasetchanged() on the list adapter? after deleting the row??

Comment: I think this is your looping problem. or after deleting one row your index remains constant. if u are using custom list there will be problem. & adapter.nofifydatasetchange() should be us.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of notifyDataSetChanged() when ever you make any changes to the adapter data which your using to populate data in ListView 
please check this [Video](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html) to know its importance